# How to say "to master Esperanto"?

Tags: translation

I obviously don't master the Esperanto language (or "have a good command of Esperanto") since I'm not even sure how to say that in Eo.

My guess is *mi mastras Esperanton*, which also reflects German *ich beherrsche Esperanto* and French *je maitrise l'espéranto*.

But according to PIV, the meaning of *mastri* is "regi, direkti, kiel mastro". Then, *mi mastras Esperanton* sounds like I am a kind of Esperanto cifal (like the Volapük cifal). Is this expression nevertheless correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The word you're looking for is indeed *regi.*

*Mastri* is a much less common word, and while it is occasionally used to describe competency in a language, it more often has a connotation closer to bossing someone around.

Comment: Good to know that "regi esperanton" is acceptable. But I still think that it goes beyond the strict definition of "regi", which conveys the idea of an actual control over something.

Answer (score 7):

Usually I hear *regi* in this context, but I think most people would also comprehend *mastri* the way you intend it. You can probably also say something like *bone koni* or *tute koni* or *bone paroli* or some such.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, is the policy to italicize words rather than put them in quotation marks?

Answer (score 3):

The verb you are looking for is [*posedi*](http://vortaro.net/#posedi), meaning 2:

> mi posedas ankaŭ tre malbone la anglan lingvon

from Zamenhof himself.

Answer (score 0):

*lerti* estas alia eblo. Oni lertas pri io. Kvankam tio ne montras plej superan nivelon, ĝi taŭgas por aliaj konoj aŭ fakoj. *Regi* estus troa por, ekzemple, matematiko, aŭ ŝufarado. Pli superan nivelon oni povas esprimi per -eg-: *lert(eg)i pri meĥaniko*.

Answer (score 0):

Tion oni ankaŭ povas esprimi per *scipovi*.

> Ili scipovas Esperanton.
> Ili scipovas paroli/skribi Esperanton.

Answer (score -2):

I normally hear *regi*, however after looking at ReVo and the Tekstaro, I don't think it is the best choice. I think that *mastri* is much better.

From the tekstaro:

> ...li mem **mastras** tiujn **lingvojn**...

Yes, the statement *Mi mastras Esperanton* is correct.

Comment: The full quote for the second example is “Male, ili asertas, ke estas venko kontraŭ Usono kiu ne plu mastras sian lingvon kaj devu akcepti ke eŭropanoj kripligas ĝin!”. I think that is a different meaning than that they don’t speak the language well. It means they no longer have control over it and it’s the Europeans who are deciding its fate. I think this matches the definition in PIV well.

Comment: Yes. The second phrase is about control over the language rather than proficiency of it. I will delete that example.